# how to find the points of the contour parts of the images using opencv python?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-preprocessing

I am trying to find the points of the contours parts(4 points) of the images (not related to the width and height of whole images).input image point are (0,0) (1300,0), (1800,0), and (1300,1800) and output image ( 0,0),(1300,0),(1600,0),(1300,1600) . My expected output should be for the bottom-left (100,1630) that mean  x will be start from  130.
my code is :

```
      contours, hierarcy=cv2.findContours(thresh_img, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
      cv2.drawContours(original_img, contours, -1, (255,120,0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
      max_contours=max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
      x,y,w,g=cv2.boundingRect(max_contours)
      cv2.rectangle(original_img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h),(0.255,0),5)
      cropped_image1=original_img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
      plt.imshow(cropped_image1)
```

How to get this type of points of the images.I have used the getperspective transform (4 points transform )I do not get the expected result. Please tell me how to do ?
Thanks....

Comment: Generally the external contour can be reduced to it 4 points using cv2.approxPolyDP(). But your page is cropped and does not show the top left corner of the page. So you will have 5 points here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments , I am trying to solve that.

Comment: Do you have an example that shows all 4 corners? If so, please post that.

Comment: I have no such example that show 4 corners of the images.

Comment: You need 4 corresponding sets of points to do perspective warp. So you need the proper corners.

Comment: Okay . Thanks you....